# Mocking Local Scope Objects using mockito or any other framework without compromising junit coverage

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Here is my problem statement with example,

```
void method1() {
    A a = new A();
    a.dosStuff();
}
```

I want to mock `a.dosStuff()` in my test using Mockito or any other framework.

I have tried with powermock it helped me out but problem is that it is not showing JUnit coverage in tools like Sonar and EclEmma.

So, is there any way to do this in Mockito or any other framework without compromising JUnit coverage?

Comment: Most often it's a code smell if you cannot test your code easily. I suggest refactoring your method instead of working around the problem with tools like Powermock (I tend to say "PowerMock is the solution for problems you should not have").

Comment: Is it the coverage of of method1 you are missing or the coverage of A.dosStuff? Because A.dosStuff is of course not covered by your unit tests when you mock it.

Comment: I would refactor this, with an injectable factory for creating the `A` object.  Then you can stub the factory so that it creates a mock.

Comment: Yes, I should have refactored the code as I am not seeing any solution rather than refactoring code.